# Jesus Christ Superstar shooting places guide?

Tags: film-location, jesus-christ-superstar

I have been up to Avdat today and I think I recognize it being used in a few scenes of the 1973 movie version of *Jesus Christ Superstar*, but of course it's really hard -- obviously they "dressed" the ruins. Is there any information about the specific locations where they filmed the movie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Songfacts interview](http://www.songfacts.com/blog/writing/jesus_christ_superstar_ted_neeley_tells_the_inside_story/) with Ted Neeley offers the following shooting locations;

> "Trial Before Caiaphas" was shot on the site of the [Herodian
>   fortresses near Bethlehem](http://www.holylandsite.com/herodianfortress.html).
>
> "The Temple" and "The Crucifixion" scenes were shot at [Avdat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avdat).
>
> [Ein 'Bokek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ein_Bokek) provided the location for "Pilate's Dream."
>
> "What's the Buzz" truly was under the Dead Sea... in a cave [[The Beit Guvrin Bell Cave]](http://forward.com/opinion/israel/200775/why-does-un-love-israeli-caves-jesus-christ-super/). The same
>   cave served as Neeley's "prison" after "The Arrest."
>
> For "King Herod's Song," the crew set up shop on the Dead Sea not far
>   from [Masada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masada#Modern_tourism), where Herod actually once had a summer palace.
>
> An ancient [Roman ampitheater in Beit 'Shaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beit_She%27an), tunneled through with
>   catacombs, served as the location for "Trial Before Pilate" and
>   "Superstar."

Note that I've corrected a couple of the place name spellings for ease of reference.

Comment: Great! It'd be even better if it included details at Avdat... also, I suspect but not 100% that Hosanna was also shot at Avdat, simply by comparing a certain shot with what I saw today.

Comment: This book about [Jesus in Cinema](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CnsgxAc0L-sC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq=Hosanna+avdat&source=bl&ots=rEL967zDEj&sig=BEMa5BEgi27rH1TNPRmzkP8LPII&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Hosanna%20avdat&f=false) would certainly suggest that that's the case